# why page is vibrating while using scrollBy()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating one directive in angularjs for smooth scrolling.. but i am facing some weird problem, whenever i am clicking any menu item the page starts vibrating and its not going up also. Its only working for downwards.. :p :).... Its kind a funny and i cant fix this problem.
Here is my code... 
**FIDDLE LINK**
https://jsfiddle.net/a6at8js6/1/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<ul class="left">
  <li ng-repeat="menu in menus"  class="list-group-item" scroll srcelem="head{{$index+1}}"><a href="">{{menu}}</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="right">
  <li ng-repeat="p in para" id="head{{$index+1}}">{{p}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
}
.right{
  float:right;
  width:500px;
}

.right li{
  height:500px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp",  []);
app.directive('scroll', function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            element.bind("click", function(e){



                var target_elem = document.getElementById(attr.srcelem);



                var divHeight = function(ele) {
                    var x = 0;
                    while (ele) {
                        x += ele.offsetTop;
                        ele = ele.offsetParent;
                    }
                    return x;
                }


                var timerID = setInterval(function() {
                    if(window.pageYOffset < divHeight(target_elem)){
                        window.scrollBy(0, 5);

                    }else if(window.pageYOffset > divHeight(target_elem)){
                        window.scrollBy(0, -5);
                    }
                    else if(window.pageYOffset === divHeight(target_elem)){
                        clearInterval(timerID);
                    }
                }, 1);


            });
        }
    };
});


app.controller("mainCtrl",  function($scope){
    $scope.menus = [1 , 2  ,3,  4,  5];
    $scope.para = ["1 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries but also the leap into electronic typesettingremaining essentially unchanged. It was popsdgsised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",  "2 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  but also the leap into electronic typesettingremaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop publishingsoftware like Aldussdgser including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",  "3 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  but also the leap into electronic typesettingremaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop publishingsoftware like Aldus PageMaker insdgsversions of Lorem Ipsum.",  "4 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to msdfbtype specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  but also the leap into electronic typesetting emaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of bm Ipsum.",  "5 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries  but also the leap into electronic typesetting remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including verssdgrem Ipsum."];
});
```

Comment: it is trapped inside loop. So it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your interval conditions are too strict and it goes around +5 and -5, if your offset is not round like 10 or 15, if it's 13 it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Modify your === condition to accept some more, like +3 and -3, not only exact same offset, and put it as the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping in intervals which does not allow your `window.pageYOffset === divHeight(target_elem)` condition to ever evaluate to true. Either change your step size or factor in the step in the condition.

If you absolutely *must* use equality, try adding a delta margin of error. I also recommend you use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.